# iCheck not working in handlebars template

Tags: javascript, html, css, icheck

```
   <script id="my-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">   
{{#each movie}}  
                <tr>     
                    <td style='vertical-align: middle;width:25%'>{{name}}</td>
                    <td style='vertical-align: middle;width:25%;text-align: center;'>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="option1" id="option1{{id}}" class="icheck"  value="{{option1}}"
                                {{#is option1 true }}
                                     checked
                                {{/is}} />
                    </td> 
                    

                </tr>
{{/each}} 
</script>
```

icheck is not working, it displays default checkbox. When used outside this script works perfectly.

Comment: what do you have `icheck` set to in your CSS?

Comment: I'm adding this icheck.min.js as my script. When I use ( class="icheck" )  outside the handlebars template it works perfectly, in handlebars is showing the default checkbox

Comment: Are you able to show more of your code so we can have a better understand of what's going on? I could be an issue outside of the line you posted.